# How would you prevent Bootstrap data migrations from running when the datasource is missing

Tags: hibernate, grails, configuration, grails-orm, grails-2.0

The grails v2.0.1 configuration has been externalized into a file so that it can be on a secure partition.

This was done by modifying Config.groovy and DataSource.groovy

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:/Volumes/secure/local.config.groovy"]
```

When this added config location isn't available, the Bootstrap code can't connect to the database and I get this confusing error:

Running Grails application
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table "USER" not found; SQL statement:
select count(*) as y0_ from user this_
; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

I would like an error that tells me that the data source isn't available. What to I need to change in my grails configuration to do that?

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        if (!User.count()) {
            setupAdminUsers() // inserts admin user for shiro
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are old style boot strap data migrations and should be added as migrations (using [database migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a conditional before running GORM is better, but still seems wrong.

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication    

    def init = { servletContext ->

        if (!grailsApplication.resources) {
           throw new RuntimeException("data source is missing")
        }

        if (!User.count()) {
            setupAdminUsers()
        }
    }
}
```